# using an array to read from a .txt file

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been staring at the code (not very productive) for about an hour. I have a .txt file that looks like this...

```
3
CSCE 155A - Fall 2011
4
Anthony Hopkins 80  90  95  87  80  78  25  17  20  22  21  24  19  22  21  23  24  21  20  25  20  55  56  110 30  20  25  8
John  Smith   99    95  82  72  64  52  15  14  11  21  25  12  19  20  21  23  21  12  12  10  15  50  50  60  25  15  20  9
Pan Mei     85  92  72  45  82  78  22  13  16  22  24  10  18  12  21  24  25  10  11  14  20  58  51  95  28  14  28  7
Rafael Vega    99   45  87  52  87  99  25  25  21  21  14  19  19  25  25  20  20  18  20  24  20  60  60  60  25  16  23  8
CSCE 155A - Spring 2012
1
Paul Kubi     80    90  5   87  80  0   25  0   20  22  21  24  19  22  21  0   24  21  20  25  20  0   0   0   30  20  25  8
CSCE 155A - Fall 2012
3
Tianna Delp   99    99  99  99  99  99  24  15  16  21  25  15  19  20  21  22  21  21  23  15  15  60  50  60  20  17  20  9
Taylor Delp   95    92  80  90  82  78  25  25  25  25  24  10  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  58  51  95  28  14  28  7
Rachel Valenz 99    45  87  52  87  99  25  25  21  21  14  19  19  25  25  20  20  18  20  24  20  60  60  60  25  16  23  8
```

I need to use arrays to read the strings and integers from this .txt file. the numbers are various homework and test scores that need to be read and they are mixed up, meaning not all the homework integers are together. The numbers before the start of each list of students in each semester and the number at the top represent number of students in that class and the number of semesters respectively. I want to know how i can use arrays to read this file and apply it to integers within the code...for loops will also be used, but I'm not that far yet...here's what i got so far

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class Student {

    int i = 1;

    String[] string = new String[i];
    int[] integer = new int[i];

    //initialize data members
    private Scanner scanner;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int assignmentScore;
    private int labScore;
    private int quizScore;
    private int homeworkScore;
    private int midterm1Score;
    private int midterm2Score;
    private int finalExamScore;
    private int zyanteScore;
    private int patScore;
    private int testScore;
    private String letterGrade;


    public void openFile(){ //method to open the grades.txt file

        try { //start try statement
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("gradesA5.txt")); //initialize scanner to scan from the grades.txt file
        } //end try statement
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //start catch statement
            System.out.println("Error opening file. Please make sure      that you have a grades.txt file in the same folder as GradeCalculator.class"); //print statement telling user that the grades.txt file is not in the right place
            System.exit(0); //system exit 
        } //end catch statement

    } //end openFile method


    public void setfirstName(){

        string [i] = scanner.next();
        i++;
        System.out.println(string [0]);
    }

    public void setlastName(){

    }

    public void setAssignmentScore(){

    }

    public void setLabScore(){

    }

    public void setQuizScore(){

    }

    public void setHomeworkscore(){

    }

    public void setMidterm1Score(){

    }

    public void setMidterm2Score(){

    }

    public void setFinalExamscore(){

    }

    public void setZyanteScore(){

    }

    public void setPATScore(){

    }

    public void setTestScore(){

    }

    public void setLetterGrade(){

    }
 }
```

I put in the print statement to test if it was reading and assigning it right

and the separate class that calls the methods...

```
 public class CourseStatistics {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student myStudent = new Student();

    myStudent.openFile();

    myStudent.setfirstName();
}

 }
```

....and the error I get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Student.setfirstName(Student.java:46)
at CourseStatistics.main(CourseStatistics.java:10)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to use arrays? If you really do, you should go through the file first to see how many rows there are, and then create your array.

Comment: Comments in the code was made by Captain Obvious:) To the topic: you should learn how to read text files, then you should parse some strings from it, and only then **arrays** will help you to store some values

Answer (score 0):

When you increment `i` in the method `setFirstName`, it goes out of bound because the variables you declared have size of 1. Try to increase the size of the array and start storing from index 0

```
int i = 1;

String[] string = new String[i];
int[] integer = new int[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you initiate an array with size 1 here:

```
int i = 1;

String[] string = new String[i];
```

And then try and assign your array @ index 1, which is out of bounds of your array, here:

```
string [i] = scanner.next();
```

Try instead:

```
string [i-1] = scanner.next();
```

Also, I see that this will happen again when you try to add another string to the array of size 1. Are you planning on adding a dynamically growing array to your Student class?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are exclusive. This means that if you set an array as such: `int[] arr = new int[5]`, the index "5" will not be available. In this case, 5 would be the size, so the index would go `0-1-2-3-4`. 
If you mean to access an array that only has a single element, you must access it with `arr[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind your code should be:

```
main:
  read the number of semesters
  create an array for n Semesters
  n times:
    read a Semester and store it in the array

reading a semester:
  read the number of students
  create an array for n Students
  n times:
    read a Student and store it in the array

reading a student:
  (left as an excercise)
```

This scheme suggests that you create a class `Semester` containing the stuents, and a class `Student` containing the grades. Another class, called `GradeProcessor` should have methods `readSemester` and `readStudent`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `array[String]` to be size `1` or `1` with this:

```
int i = 1;

String[] string = new String[i];
```

When you go and reference `[i]`, which is `1` and the size is `1`, and you have to remember that the fist index is represented by `0`. You would have to reference `0`. I'm also not sure that you mean to initialize the array to size 1.

```
public void setfirstName(){
    string [i] = scanner.next();
    i++;
    System.out.println(string [0]);
}
```